# Copy webpart page from one site to another site through sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to move webpart page containg content editor webpart from the one site  to another site through sharepoint designer but the page is moved without its content so how to move page with its content anyone can tell me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. If you are doing this in development farm you can try  [SPContentDeploymentWizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/). You need to export the page with all it's reference and then import it in destination.